# Delete and count files older than eg. 31 days

Tags: powershell

I have tried to find a solution for a PowerShell-script, that can delete all files in a folder and subfolders, older than eg. 31 days.

It could be nice to get the number of files deleted and the total amount of files in the folders.

I should use it for posting on Slack, thats why I would like to have the number of files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Comment: Are you still stuck on this?

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of your question, here is a approach you could take to do most of what you need. I use this myself to clear out a folder.

```
$Path = C:\test
$DaysBack = "-31" 
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($DaysBack)

#delete files from $Path directory that are older than $Daysback
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include * -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete} | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Force
```

You will then just need to add some logging to either count the files and folders before running the deletion, for counting both files and folders you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
```

Or for just counting files as you requested, you can specify it after the `GetChildItem`with the `-File` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | ForEachObject{$_.Count}
```